# Batteries connection for 3 wheel e-bike

Tags: batteries

Goodday. I need info on this. If i connect say 3 x 12 volt 28amp batteries in parallel to increase the amp hour that makes it a big 12 volt battery and then connect 2 x 24 volt but lower in amps battery in series to make a 48 volt battery and conect these together to make  a 60 volt with the 1st one bigger amps, will it work. It will be for a electric scooter. All will be a gel batteries.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect five 12v batteries in series, you will end up with a 60v battery.

If the five batteries have different capacities, then on discharge, the lowest capacity battery / batteries will be discharged before the others. When this happens, you must stop drawing power. If you don't, the discharged batteries could be discharged to damagingly low voltage levels, and if you still draw power, become reverse charged (properly damaged!) by the others.

To avoid this happening, it necessary to monitor the voltage of each battery, or at least the low capacity ones, individually, and stop drawing power once the first battery reaches its minimum safe voltage.

Of course, this will happen while the other batteries still have charge, so a series arrangement of different capacity batteries will be heavier and more expensive than a matched set that can deliver the same total energy.

It's worth noting that 60v is higher than most authorities would rate as a touch safe low voltage. 48v is generally reckoned to be the highest you can go before you need to start paying proper 'high voltage' attention to insulation and separation gaps.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you do not do this:

12 V batteries has 28 A its rated current capacity, such three in parallel means 28*3 A , and if the series connected batteries (2*24 V) does not have that much rating it would deteriorate their performance. Also it may lead to overheating of lower amp. rated batteries.

Even if you addressed the aforementioned issue by connecting 24 V battery of 28*3 A current rating, the equal current sharing among three parallel connected 12 V batteries is also not guaranteed unless you have some power electronics interface in between (due to different state of charge of batteries).